# Cannot find.json file (Node.js NPM game programming)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to use NPM to draw tiles onto my canvas and I was successfully doing it. I made a json file to try to store the tile data for each level and tried to load it. However, it gives me a 404 not found error and the "levels" folder doesn't appear under sources when I inspect it on Chrome.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code for the main.js:

```
import SpriteSheet from './SpriteSheet.js';
import {loadImage, loadLevel} from './loaders.js';

const canvas = document.getElementById('screen');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

loadImage('/img/tiles.png')
.then(image => {
    const sprites = new SpriteSheet(image, 16, 16);
    sprites.define('ground', 0, 0);
    sprites.define('sky', 3, 23);

    loadLevel('1-1')
    .then(level => {
        console.log(level);
    });

    for (let x = 0; x < 25; ++x){
        for (let y = 0; y < 14; ++y){
            sprites.drawTile('sky', context, x, y);
        }
    }

    for (let x = 0; x < 25; ++x){
        for (let y = 12; y < 14; ++y){
            sprites.drawTile('ground', context, x, y);
        }
    }
});
```

For loaders.js:

```
export function loadImage(url){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(image);
        });
        image.src = url;
    });
}

export function loadLevel(name){
    return fetch('/levels/${name}.json')
    .then(r => r.json());   
}
```

and 1-1.json:

```
{
    "backgrounds": [
        {
            "tile": "sky",
            "ranges": [
                [
                    0, 25,
                    0, 14
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I attached an image of my folders just in case. img contains the tile img I'm using, js has main.js and loaders.js, and levels only has 1-1.

[image]

Comment: everything looks fine, try `loadImage('./img/tiles.png')`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `loadImage('../img/tiles.png')`?

Comment: What do you mean? I have no problem loading the image. My problem is that I can't load 1-1.json into loadLevel.

Comment: My bad. First of all, I think it's the same issue, you are addressing the `levels` folder as if it were inside the `js` folder. Try using `../levels/${name}.json`. Second, if you are using string literals, you must use backticks instead of single quotes.

Comment: The problem was actually just the backticks. I used backticks on loaders.js and it worked. Thank you very much! 
I still don't quite get why though, since when importing everywhere else single quotes are still used.

Comment: Great! It's because in this particular case you are using `${}` which requires backticks. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use back-tick (` `) instead of single quote in `return fetch('/levels/${name}.json')` to be

```
return fetch(`/levels/${name}.json`)
```

For more information Please find Javascript [Template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)